# What's the most efficient way to randomly change the color of 15 buttons, programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The only way I can think to do this is to use :

```
var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 6
    switch(RandomNumber){
    case 0:
```

and then have different "cases" whereby it activates the button color.

What I would like is a way to randomly find a color and insert it into the line, but I don't know if this is possible, and if it is possible, what would be the correct syntax?

For example, if I assign "UIColor.blueColor()" to a variable  ex. buttonBlue, is it possible to insert it into a line of code.. i.e.

UIButton tempButton?.backgroundColor = buttonBlue    ?

or do I have do it the long way and have many switches for each button (there are 15 buttons)

I would like to have one random switch and use it for all 15 buttons, than to have 15 random switches, generating more lines of code.  Sounds very inefficient.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prepare the 15 different colors you like (`UIColor.blueColor()`, `UIColor.redColor()`, ...) and store them into an array.

Then in order to generate a random color you would just have to randomly choose a number between 0 and 14 and get the corresponding element from the array.

Comment: so would this code actually work by inserting the variable buttonColor: UIButton tempButton?.backgroundColor = buttonColor    ? or could you please tell me how I insert the variable containing the random color from the array? thanks

Comment: if buttonColor is an UIColor sure it should !

Comment: I tried this: whiteTile1.backgroundColor = colorw1  , but it said that NSString is not a subtype of UIColor  how to fix? thanks

Comment: How has colorw1 been declared ?

Comment: how should I declare it?  Thanks for your patience, I am learning.  I just have it declared as a var string.  and also using this code : colorw1 = colorarray[ofTwelve()]       since [ofTwelve] is this function:  func ofTwelve() -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random() % 12)
    }  since I have 12 random colors

Comment: if you want blue : var colorw1 = UIColor.blueColor()

Comment: actually .. whiteTile1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()  gives me the same error

Comment: actually .. whiteTile1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()  works, but whiteTile1.backgroundColor = colorw1   does not work , even though colorw1 = "UIColor.blueColor()"

Comment: remove the " " around UIColor.blueColor() in your colorw1 declaration

Comment: I see my mistake, I used quotes ...  duh!

Comment: i would upvote you and choose you as the correct answer but apparently my rep is too low to do that?  I am a bit confused how I get the 5 rep needed to do this simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below custom function:

```
func getRandomColor() -> UIColor{
    var randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
    var randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
    var randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
    return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
}
```